# Valgrind produces erroneous output on my machine

Tags: c, memory-management, valgrind

Here's a small C program I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Prototypes */
int sum(int *summands, unsigned int n);
void increment(char *string, int n);
void copy(char *src, char *dst);

int main(void)
{
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    char str1[] = "HAL";
    char str2[] = "SRIKANT";
    char str3[] = "A string to be copied.";
    char *str4 = malloc(sizeof(str3));

    printf("The sum of all the elements in ARR is %d.\n", sum(arr, 9));

    printf("STR1 is: %s. STR2 is: %s.\n", str1, str2);
    printf("Incrementing all letters...\n");
    increment(str1, 3);
    increment(str2, 7);
    printf("Incremented!\n");
    printf("STR1 is now: %s. STR2 is now: %s.\n", str1, str2);

    copy(str3, str4);
    printf("STR4 is: %s\n", str4);
    free(str4);

    return 0;
}

/* Returns the sum of all the elements in SUMMANDS. */
int sum(int *summands, unsigned int n)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < (int) n; i++)
    {
        sum += *(summands + i);
    }
    return sum;
}

/* Increments all the letters in the string STRING, held in an array of length N.
 * Does not modify any other memory which has been previously allocated. */
void increment(char *string, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        (*(string + i))++;
    }
}

/* Copies the string SRC to DST. */
// void copy(char *src, char *dst)
// {
//     while (*src)
//     {
//         *dst++ = *src++;
//     }
//     *dst = '\0';
// }

void copy(char *src, char *dst)
{
    while ((*dst++ = *src++));
}
```

When I run the executable with Valgrind on my machine running Linux Mint 18, it produces the following erroneous report (heap summary):

```
==5503== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==5503== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==5503== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==5503== Command: ./disc1_q4
==5503== 
The sum of all the elements in ARR is 45.
STR1 is: HAL. STR2 is: SRIKANT.
Incrementing all letters...
Incremented!
STR1 is now: IBM. STR2 is now: TSJLBOU.
STR4 is: A string to be copied.
==5503== 
==5503== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5503==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5503==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 1,047 bytes allocated
==5503== 
==5503== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==5503== 
==5503== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==5503== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

But when I run the same program with Valgrind on the Cloud 9 IDE (which uses a Ubuntu virtual machine), it produces the correct report:

```
==2359== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2359== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2359== Using Valgrind-3.10.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2359== Command: ./disc1_q4
==2359== 
The sum of all the elements in ARR is 45.
STR1 is: HAL. STR2 is: SRIKANT.
Incrementing all letters...
Incremented!
STR1 is now: IBM. STR2 is now: TSJLBOU.
STR4 is: A string to be copied.
==2359== 
==2359== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2359==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2359==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 23 bytes allocated
==2359== 
==2359== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==2359== 
==2359== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==2359== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Why is Valgrind producing incorrect results on my machine?

Comment: Why do you think it is erroneous? What proof do you have before you accuse your system? _humans!!_

Comment: @MichaelWalz  are you sure?

Comment: I've seen many lines like `char *str4 = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(str3) + 1));`, not sure what sizeof(str3) would return, is it the size of the array, is it the size of a char pointer?

Comment: @SouravGhosh, it is clear from the code that I've made only one heap allocation and subsequently freed it, yet Valgrind on my machine reports that I've made two allocs and two frees. Why? Also, it reports that I've allocated 1,047 bytes on the heap, whereas that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: i dont see your problem, what exaclty is the error?

Comment: @Blauelf, `malloc(sizeof(str3))` works because of the way I've initialized `str3`. Initializing `str3` the way I have does not have the effect of storing a pointer to the string "A string to be copied." inside `str3`, but rather the actual characters themselves are stored inside the corresponding elements of the `str3` array. Had I initialized `str3` as `char *str3 = "A string to be copied.";`, then I would have to use `char *str4 = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(str3) + 1));` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect `printf()` allocates memory in one case which you think as "erroneous".

It wouldn't be unrealistic for your libc's `printf()` implementation allocates some memory internally; it's not erroneous.

Valgrind catches all the allocations and reports it even though your program itself didn't allocate it. You can test this by commenting out the `printf()`'s. Similarly, other standard functions could do memory allocations as well. So, you can't control it and there are not "wrong". You don't need to worry about the "total allocations" as long as there's no leak reported.

Comment: What do you mean by "your libc's `printf()` implementation"? Shouldn't the implementation of `printf()` be the same across all Linux OS's?

Comment: @SassySamurai *Shouldn't the implementation of printf() be the same across all Linux OS's?* - It doesn't have to be; one can very well use a different libc other than glibc. Besides, even with same libc but different versions, the implementation might change.